# How to convert raw unicode to utf8-unicode in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

first timer here, I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can.

I'm working with python2.7 inside Maya.
I got a string (called an attribute) 'attr' that is imported with Maya's API and goes as followed:

```
print(attr)
print(type(attr))

>> GÃ©nÃ©rique
>> <type 'unicode'>
```

I need to convert this to a utf-8 readable format before I can go forward with my work.
Basically I need to be able to do this:

```
print(attr)
print(type(attr))

>>Générique
>><type 'unicode'>
```

I've tried multiple combinations with attr.encode / attr.decode but I cannot really grasp what I should be doing.
What bothers me most is when I try to manually type the variable in the code you can actually get this:

```
attr = 'GÃ©nÃ©rique'
print(type(attr))
attr = attr.decode('utf-8')
print(attr)
print(type(attr))

>><type 'str'>
>>Générique
>><type 'unicode'>
```

So I get that I should be converting 'attr' to a str type initially, but I can't do it without losing information in it.

Any ideas ? please ?

Edit : solved by snakecharmerb (and ftfy). Thanks a lot. both solutions under this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is text that was originally UTF-8 but decoded with an 8-bit encoding, likely latin-1 or cp1252.  To fix the text you need to encode to the 8-bit encoding to get the UTF-8 bytes and then decode.

```
>>> u = u'GÃ©nÃ©rique'
>>> fixed = u.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
>>> print fixed
Générique
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

I found out about the module FTFY. Was a bit of a hassle to make pip work with Maya but it's all fine and done.
To anyone with the same issue:
make pip work with maya:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/can-i-use-pip-in-maya-script-editor/td-p/7638107
(you'll need to run admin cmd or it won't install)

grab ftfy (version below 5 was compatible with python2.7):
pip install ftfy==4.4.3

my unclean code looks like this :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.utils
import unicodedata
import StringIO
import codecs
import sys
import re
from ftfy import fix_text

attr = cmds.getAttr(*objectName*)
attr = fix_text(attr)
print(attr)
```